# Why is my HTML form validation error message displaying so far to the right?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, validation, cjk, register-transfer-level

The error message is displayed too far on the right as you can see on this picture of the validation error message

[image]

```
<%= form_for @listing do |f| %>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 select">
<div class="form-group">
<label>お家の種類</label>
<%= f.select :home_type, [["一軒家","一軒家"], ["マンション","マンション"], ["アパート","アパート"]], {prompt:"選択してください"}, {required: 'true', autofocus: 'true', class: 'form-control'} %>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<br>
...

<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-danger" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

How should I fix the validation message position?

Comment: What language/environment is this?

Comment: ruby on rails. chrome version 54.0.2840.99 m

Comment: I cannot see the picture.

Comment: sorry I updated the photo.

Comment: Does Japanese count as a RTL language?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control the positioning or formatting of these error balloons. They are built into the browser. The spec does not specify their appearance or location.